# Is there a way to make custom crafting tables show available recipes? (Minecraft Bedrock Addon 1.20.30)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

In my latest addon, I've encountered a problem where crafting recipes only show for the vanilla crafting table, and not for the two custom ones I've added. So, recipes which are tagged with only the custom crafting table don't show up at all, but if you put in the right ingredients, it will then show (and give) the correct output.

To put it another way, my custom table recipes *work*, but the person downloading my addon has *no way of knowing that they exist*. Some recipes are very non-obvious, and likely wouldn't be figured out by trial and error.

Currently I'm considering leaving some kind of in-game documentation (for example, a library with books showing the recipes) and/or adding a complete list of these to the pack description on Planet Minecraft. But, I would much prefer if there is a way to show the recipes without requiring users to read documentation.

Here is a screenshot of a **custom** recipe showing correctly for the **vanilla** crafting table:
[image]

And, here is a custom recipe *not* showing up in one of my **custom** crafting tables:
[image]

Both recipes' JSON files, to show the patterns & unlock ingredients:

**Vanilla Table Recipe**

```
{
    "format_version": "1.20.30",
    "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "moon:shimmerstem"
        },

        "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
        
        "pattern": [
            "#",
            "B"
        ],
        "key": {
            "#": {
                "item": "moon:desiccated_shimmerstem"
            },
            "B": {
                "item": "minecraft:potion"
            }
        },
        "unlock": [
            {
                "item": "moon:desiccated_shimmerstem",
                "data": 0
            }
        ],
        "result": [ // Reference: https://wiki.bedrock.dev/loot/recipes.html
            {
                "item": "moon:shimmerstem"
            },
            "minecraft:glass_bottle"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Custom Table Recipe**

```
{
    "format_version": "1.20.30",
    "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "moon:desiccated_shimmerstem"
        },

        "tags": [ "extracter" ],
        
        "pattern": [
            "#",
            "B"
        ],
        "key": {
            "#": {
                "item": "moon:shimmerstem"
            },
            "B": {
                "item": "minecraft:glass_bottle"
            }
        },
        "unlock": [
            {
                "item": "moon:shimmerstem",
                "data": 0
            }
        ],
        "result": [ // Reference: https://wiki.bedrock.dev/loot/recipes.html
            {
                "item": "moon:desiccated_shimmerstem"
            },
            "minecraft:potion"
        ]
    }
}
```